# Can I make a pen draw a solid line?

Tags: dynamic-paint

I have tried to make an animated pen draw a solid, curving line - with limited results! I tried dynamic paint, but couldn't get a decent line, just a big fuzzy mess! The best I could do was with a particle system, but that is made of dots and, the faster the pen moves the further apart the dots appear - not quite like the kind of line a pen makes. I don't want a pre-determined (animated) line, I just want it to draw wherever I make the pen go. Is this easy, or a bit of a tall order?

1. Dynamic Paint

   [image: Using Dynamic Paint]
2. Particle System

   [image: Using aParticle System]

Answer (score 9):

**There is more than likely a better way to go about this…** but for the time being, it seems this can occur for several reasons, such as how dense your canvas is and the size of the part of the *'brush'* touching the canvas etc.

Using the default *canvas* and *brush* settings for the most part, you can get around this easily enough by cranking up the number of subdivisions in your canvas mesh and optionally by increasing your Sub-Steps.

[image]

Comment: I have tried this previously, but found it to be too slow to make it worth while! - Maybe a script could be written to 'join the dots'?? - beyond my ability at this stage. :)

Comment: @SteveW as I said, __there is likely a better way..__ :) I don't use dynamic paint much so I'm not sure. It would also help if you mention what you have tried in the future.

Comment: you're right, more detail would have helped. It's a while since I was working on this, and I just thought it might be worth asking.

Comment: @SteveW the only other suggestion I could give is to use a larger brush and scale/resize the rest of your scene accordingly.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I'll see if I can make it work. Could be a bit tricky to resize, though, as the pen is part of a machine (harmonograph) that I struggled to make in the first place!! :)